# Duvida com Joins em consulta HQL

Tags: hql

Estou com o seguinte problema ao realizar uma consulta no banco com HQL

A tabela `tabela1` possui aproximadamente 20000 registros.

As demais tabelas possuem "N" registros.

A tabela `tabela1` possui relacionamentos com as demais tabelas `tabela2`, `tabela3` e `tabela4`.

Ao executar  este comando que  está  abaixo eu esperava que o valor de retorno fosse o valor igual ao número de registros da `tabela 1`, mas estou fazendo alguma coisa errada com os *JOINS* pois o comando me retorna um numero superior  a 200000 ;

```
select distinct count(t.id)
from tabela1 t  
left join t.tabela2 t2
left join t.tabela3 t3
left join t.tabela4 t4 
where t2.campoInteiro >-1 ;
```

As tabelas estao assim:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 List<Tabela2> tabela2;
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 List<Tabela3> tabela3;
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 List<Tabela4> tabela4;
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa definir como as tabelas se conectam. Da forma que está, todas as linhas da `t1` se juntam às da `t2`, `t3` e `t4`.

```
select distinct count(t.id)
from tabela1 t  
left join t.tabela2 t2 on t2.fk_t1 = t1.pk_t1
left join t.tabela3 t3 on t3.fk_t2 = t2.pk_t2
left join t.tabela4 t4 on t4.fk_t3 = t3.pk_t3
where t2.campoInteiro > -1 ;
```

Comment: Quando eu faço um Hql deste  modo eu  ainda  preciso referenciar a pk com fk?  ex: select distinct count(t.id)   from tabela1 t  
left join t.tabela2 t2

Comment: Não funciona o HQL desta  forma ele não reconhece a comparação t1.tabela2.id =t2.id

Comment: Por [esse link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21980068/4551469) realmente está errado, não tem necessidade do `on`, o join seria feito "automaticamente".. mas você precisa garantir que exista uma relação entre as tabelas.

Comment: Deu  uma  exceção : query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
  [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlia@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: Meu  mapeamento esta  assim :   List<Tabela2> tabela2;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Tabela3> tabela3;

Comment: bota o mapeamento das tabelas na pergunta, pra ver se ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, faltou aí, (boas práticas) na declaração das anotações de relacionamento (@oneToMany) a definição do tipo de carregamento das listas (t2, t3, etc) quando carregado a t1 na qual está relacionada, pra não comprometer a performance da consulta. Ficaria assim:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<Tabela2> tabela2;
 @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 List<Tabela3> tabela3;
 @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 List<Tabela4> tabela4;
```

E na consulta deve-se inicializar esses "Lazy", ficando assim:

```
select distinct count(t.id)
from tabela1 t  
left join fetch t.tabela2 t2
left join fetch t.tabela3 t3
left join fetch t.tabela4 t4 
where t2.campoInteiro >-1 ;
```